# localhost page not found, but found with port 8080

Tags: apache, localhost, ampps

[image]I’m a beginner and I did everything according to the book, I downloaded the ampps program, but there was a problem that port 80 for Apache was already in use and I changed the port to 8080 in the configuration file, everything worked, but it didn’t connect to the localhost itself, but if you specify the localhost:8080 it comes in and shows the ampps file directory, but when I try to go to the configuration folder in the browser it says that there is no access, what should I do to make the localhost work?

I have poor knowledge of English, so for the most part I looked for a solution in Russian and found nothing

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to access your app with http in the URL not https when developing locally. You may have your web browser set to automatically try to upgrade the connection from http to https.

Answer (score 2):

try to check firewall configuration: Ensure that your firewall or antivirus software is not blocking port 8080. You may need to create an exception for Apache in your firewall settings or update the virtual host configuration: You may need to modify the virtual host configuration file. It typically looks like httpd-vhosts.conf. Here's an example of how you can set up a virtual host for port 8080:`<VirtualHost *:8080> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/your/htdocs" ServerName localhost </VirtualHost>`

Now, try accessing http://localhost in your browser without specifying the port. It should work with port 8080.

Comment: I tried to log in by completely disabling the firewall, it didn’t help, the _httpd-vhosts.conf_ file says *“#DO NOT EDIT, CREATED BY AMPPS”*